# url rewriting of asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a domain A.com, containing 2 asp.net applications 'B' and 'C'
where both B and C are related by reference.
I want.. on entering url www.A.com users should open up the page www.A.com/B/Default.aspx but address bar should show www.A.com
url rewriting within project application B and C are working fine. But how can i set up url rewriting outside the projects in the root directory.
I have tried out the tutorials present in http://urlrewriter.net/ and http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx
and these are working fine for project B and C...

but i cant set up the configuration in web.config file in the root directory. The problem is with rewriting a page from outside the project. Do I need to make some settings in the IIS. I am using godaddy' windows hosting.

please help...

---

It will be great if you can help me with the code. Thanks..
I am using this web.config setting in project B while rewriting pages within B.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="B.Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, B.Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="B.Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, B.Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>    
  </system.web>
  <rewriter>
      <rewrite url="/Default.aspx" to="/About.aspx"/>
  </rewriter>
```

where i am referring the url rewrting dll present here https://github.com/sethyates/urlrewriter

But I cant set up the web.config setting in the root directory for redirecting from www.A.com to www.A.com/B/Default.aspx
It will be great if you can help me with some basic idea or code... thanks..

Answer (score 0):

urlrewriter comes with source code and you can modify the code and rebuild it. The code is for generic usage but your's is specific one. So make some changes in the code and you can achieve what you want. Let me know if you want me to help you with the code